# How to rotate with two reference points?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I would like to emulate a similar feature in softwares like Autodesk CAD, Sketchup, Rhino.

I'm using blender v2.81a and I want to rotate an object by referencing two points. Like in the picture, I would like to rotate the box on the left by cliking one of its vertices (p1) and then clicking a vertex of another object(p2) to perfectly align the edges of the two objects.

Answer (score 10):

1. Put the 3D cursor where you want the pivot of your rotation to be. This is easiest to do if you already have a vertex there, which in your case you do. go into edit mode, select the desired vertex, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, then 'Cursor to Selected' or 'Cursor to Active'.
2. Set your pivot point to 3D cursor. This can be done with <kbd>.</kbd> or in the UI.
3. Set your snap settings to the following. The important parts are Snap to Vertex, Snap with Active, and Affect Rotate in your case. Make sure snap is turned on.

[image]

4. Go into edit mode of the plane you want to rotate. Select everything by hitting <kbd>A</kbd>. Deselect and then reselect your 'active' vertex, which is the part you want to align.
5. Hit <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate. The plane should rotate so that a line from the 3D cursor (pivot point) through the active vertex now points to the vertex closest to your mouse cursor.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! So fast! with a gif! You are the savior of the day.
Blender really should make this simpler though.

Comment: I know a rework of the snap system is on a list for 'eventually'. I think it's a pretty powerful feature, but you do have to know all the little settings to get exactly what you want. There's some stuff that is basically useless though, like snap to edge.

Comment: Hmm. Can this method applied with empty? After trying for an hour I think not.

Comment: @Rekov Wow. So nice to see that the snap system actually works. I learned a lot here :).